# Prevent geometry features being drawn if it's outside of a given layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I just started experimenting with OpenLayers 4, and I have the following problem:

I have a map with a default raster(OSM), and on top of it a vector layer for drawing features, that covers only a small area. Now when I start drawing (e.g.) a polygon within this area(orange) I don't want the user be able to pull the blue form(form to be drawn) out of this while editing.
Or just disable drawing geometry features on the raster layer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done [a sample](https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/00d60bd321570521c2bf03649280c336) doing this kind of things.

They are two mains parts (some incomplete excerpts to illustrate):

- a function to manage condition(s) to use draw interaction

  ```
  var conditionNoModifierKeysWithin = function(mapBrowserEvent) {
    // Spatial constraints
    var drawWithin = rewindedPolygons.features.some(feat => {
      return turf.booleanPointInPolygon(
        ol.proj.toLonLat(mapBrowserEvent.coordinate),
        feat
      );
    });

    var originalEvent = mapBrowserEvent.originalEvent;
    // condition combining keyboard keys & the spatial contraints
    return (
      !originalEvent.altKey &&
        !(originalEvent.metaKey || originalEvent.ctrlKey) &&
        !originalEvent.shiftKey &&
        drawWithin);
  };
  ```
- The `condition` option when instantiating your draw interaction e.g

  ```
  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    condition: conditionNoModifierKeysWithin,
    source: source,
  ```